# logrotate not removing old files

Tags: log, logrotate

I'm trying to create a logrotate configuration that is the same for all log files. Right now I have

```
/var/log/* {
   size 100k
   rotate 5
   missingok
   compress
}
```

I created a shell script that makes dummy log files to test logrotate's capabilities. The script is

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do
   echo $RANDOM > /var/log/Random.log.${i};
done;
touch -a -m -t 201512180130.09 /var/log/Random.log*
```

However, when I run `sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf` the Random.log* files are compressed, but I am still retaining all 100 log files instead of just 5.

Please help!